# Using requestValidationMode="2.0" in ASP.NET MVC 3 (.NET 4.0)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

I need to disable the request validation for single controller method. 
(A service is posting xml to me and I have no control over the encoding etc.)

So setting 
`[ValidateInput(false)]` on the Method and having `requestValidationMode="2.0"` on the `httpruntime` tag in the `web.config` works.

But what I don't like is reverting to a less secure model, just to get on single method working.

Is my assumption correct, that it is less secure? 
Or is there a way of recieving this post withouth disabling the .`Net` validation model?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't really know the difference between the different validation modes.

However you can put a ValidateInput(false) and use Request.Unvalidated() to capture a specific property.

Comment: If you don't know, you shouldn't answer.